Dynamically update the "initial_visible_month" from dcc.DatePickerRange. Python Plotly Dash
I want to know if it is possible to dynamically update the initial_visible_month value.
For exemple: the start_date is 01/01/2024 and the end_date is 31/21/2024. If the user clicks to edit the start date, the initial_visible_month value becomes the start_date, and if the users click to edit the end date, the initial_visible_month value becomes the end_date.
I tried using the callbacks but I don't know how to get the inputs when the user clicks to pick the date. I want to know if it is possible to do that and if it does, how can I do it.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

It is possible to update initial_visible_month using callbacks and callback_context. The callback_context is the key to understanding which component, property and value was updated to trigger the callback. By inspecting the data from ctx.args_grouping you can determine if the start_date or end_date was edited and get the new value.
See the callback context documentation.

Here is a demo app to show how to capture the changed value and update initial_visible_month.
   from dash import Dash, html, dcc, Input, Output, State, ctx, no_update

   # initialize the dash app as 'app'
   app = Dash(__name__)

   beginning_date = "2024-01-01"
   ending_date = "2024-12-31"

   # set up the app layout
   app.layout = html.Div(
       children=[
           html.H1(children="Test Dashboard"),
           html.P(id="my-paragraph"),
           dcc.DatePickerRange(
               id="my-date-picker-range",
               start_date=beginning_date,
               end_date=ending_date,
           ),
       ]
   )


   @app.callback(
       Output("my-paragraph", "children"),
       Output("my-date-picker-range", "initial_visible_month"),
       State("my-date-picker-range", "initial_visible_month"),
       Input("my-date-picker-range", "start_date"),
       Input("my-date-picker-range", "end_date"),
   )
   def initial_visible_month_change(initial_visible_month, start_date, end_date):

       triggered_id = ctx.triggered_id

       if triggered_id == "my-date-picker-range":

           for possible_triggers in ctx.args_grouping:
               if possible_triggers["triggered"] is True:

                   if possible_triggers["property"] == "start_date":
                       initial_visible_month = start_date
                   elif possible_triggers["property"] == "end_date":
                       initial_visible_month = end_date
   
                   paragraph_text = f"initial_visible_month is {initial_visible_month} and set by {possible_triggers['property']}"

                   return (paragraph_text, initial_visible_month)

       paragraph_text = f"initial_visible_month is {initial_visible_month}"
       return (paragraph_text, no_update)


   if __name__ == "__main__":
       app.run(debug=True)

